# What the following statement is doing in the ripple effect function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, effect, ripple

**var top= e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight/2 - document.body.scrollTop;**

Could anyone explain what each part of the above statement is doing?

'e.target' is the object which triggers the event and ripple is the span containing the ripple class, therefore, if it is the ripple itself.So it is finding its position in relation to the top of the page, why it references rect  and ripple at the same time?

Here is a better context of the function:

```
if(!ripple){
    ripple=document.createElment('span'); /*empty object, span to hold the ripple class*/
    ripple.className='ripple';/*add ripple class to it (span)*/

    /*place the ripple on top of the button*/
    ripple.style.height=ripple.style.width=
    Math.max(rect.width, rect.height)+'px';
    /*set the ripple to the buttons child= attach*/
    target.appendChild(ripple);
}

/*---------  DONT ANIMATE FOR NOW  --------------*/
ripple.classList.remove('show');

/* complex part*/
var top= e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight/2 - document.body.scrollTop;  /*DEBUG HERE*/
var left =e.pageX - rect.left - ripple.offsetWidth/2 - document.body.scrollLeft;                          
ripple.style.top= top + 'px';
ripple.style.left= left + 'px';
```

Comment: Hey El.oz, what I can't get my head around is this, I know it creates a span then attach the class which creates the effect, the button listens for clicks and gets position where the span containing the effect is the clicked  which is got by getting the event.pageY and page X, so why is the script  is taking (-) from 'rect.top' then taking again from ripple.offsetHeight?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I figure out the **answer**, when we coders don't understand what a piece of code is doing it is no good to see it take it for granted and use it as we wish, we Must know what each line does. Thanks to  El.oz and some more research I think it is done. So... Here it is how  is supposed to work:

---

When we click anywhere in the page pageX/Y give us the absolute position, that is, the position in relation to the document, but if we want to affect a particular object in the doc we have to convert these coordinates into local space,in other words, a position relative to the object we clicked on, which is defined by a rectangle area which encloses every object and last but not least as we want to to sit a span wherever we click, it makes sense to use its center as registration point instead of using upper right corner.

---

Data we need :

---

- Gets the global position:    event.pageX / event.pageY
- Get the position of the object we clicked on => Container offsetLeft / offsetTop
- Change the registration point of the object we want to place from upper right corner to center, which in our case is the ripple => Ripple clientWidth /2  clientHeight/2 =>

---

- The Math involved:  We subtract any offset from the global coords
  in our case we take out the offset of the container and the any offset caused by page scroll in both axis and finally center the span in the click position.
  And this is it, the span contains the classe which performs the animation of the ripple.

---

```
var top= e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight/2 - document.body.scrollTop; /*subtract the container and scroll offset from global then center, this gives the local coordinate*/
var left =e.pageX - rect.left - ripple.offsetWidth/2 - document.body.scrollLeft;                          
ripple.style.top= top + 'px'; /*place the ripple on this local coords*/
ripple.style.left= left + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'm not so good in explaining but i will try to simplify it as i could.

The display of `span` tags is inline, so it will not take the width nor height. instead set it in `display block`, or give it `padding`.

Second to make the element take his position from mouse point you should get this things:

- Set the ripple in `absolute` position
- Get the:

  - `event.pageX` / `event.pageY`
  - Container `offsetLeft` / `offsetTop`
  - Ripple `clientWidth` / `clientHeight` and divide it with 2 to center it with pointer

```js
var cont = document.querySelector('.cont');

var ripple = document.createElement('span');
ripple.setAttribute('class', 'ripple');
ripple.style.width = '40px';
ripple.style.height = '30px';
ripple.style.display = 'block';
ripple.style.position = 'absolute';
ripple.style.backgroundColor = '#2ecc71';

cont.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var posX =  e.pageX  - cont.offsetLeft - (ripple.clientWidth/2);
  var posY =  e.pageY  - cont.offsetTop - (ripple.clientHeight/2);
  ripple.style.left = posX + 'px';
  ripple.style.top = posY + 'px';
  cont.appendChild(ripple);
});
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfzjk24r

**Jquery Expample:** http://codepen.io/El-Oz/pen/reQpae